# How to comprehend the precision-recall-fscore array over an LSTM or Convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I have been trying to use an LSTM network for sequence classification. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1, 30)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 30
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 400, epochs = 20, verbose = 1)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred.round()))
```

The output of precision_recall_fscore_support:

> (array([ 0.       ,  0.       ,  0.5199002,  0.5197487,  0.       ,
>           0.       ,  0.       ]), array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.62014302,  0.38130374,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ]), array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.56561448,  0.43989032,  0.        ,
>           0.        ,  0.        ]), array([    0,     0, 48384, 48384,     0,     0,     0])

As each array has two non-zero scores, what is the accurate score of each metric? Isn't the output meant to be a single value for each of precision, recall and f-score measures?

Answer (score 0):

The `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support` function call returns a sequence of 4 arrays corresponding to each of the measure, and each array records the score for each label in your classification problem. (Read [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) for documentation)

I'm assuming you had a 7 label classification problem, hence seven scores per each array. The 0 values indicated that you're getting zero precision/recall over those labels.

Comment: But then, why do the ensemble algorithms like RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier, etc. return just a single value for each of the metric and why not sequences as in above case?

Comment: it is not dependent on the algorithm you used for classification; evaluating metrics on final predictions depends on your choice. This sklearn function takes the parameter `average` where you can specify different options for the kind of precision recall values you want. You have the choice of setting `average="micro"` or `average="macro"` to get single value based on different schemes, You should really go through the documentation page and the precision recall concepts once. :)